# NSFetchedResultsController while updating while scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

If the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is processing an update (item deletion for example)
and the user scrolls the UITableView at the same time.

What happens if the UITableView needs to access a fetch request item that is being deleted ?
Should I test that in cellForRowAtIndexPath and how ?

Or is it impossible to occur ?

Comment: Having done some testing it seems it's necessary to lock the NSFetchedResultsController's NSManagedObjectContext so we are sure it's not updated when cellForRowAtIndexPath is reading it. Anyone could confirm that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue. Core Data and table views handle this.

Just make sure that you update your table view after managed object(s) have been inserted and/or deleted.

The easiest way is to have the table view `reloadData` in the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate method `controllerDidChangeContent:`.

To do fancier stuff like animate rows in to or out of the table, check out the boiler plate code in the Typical Use section of the [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: While using `reloadData` will work, using it in conjunction with `NSFetchedResultsController` is a bit counter productive as it will cause all cells to reload. This is an expensive operation especially when you have tables that can be hundreds of cells in length (like chat conversations).